# How to white list postfix smtp senders

Tags: 12.04, postfix, mail, smtp

My mail server (postfix, ubuntu, courier) got compromised by spammers that sent plenty of dummy mails to many recipients,

The spammers used two different ways:

1. using real domain on my server but fake user account that wasn't exit
2. using fake sender mail (user and domain),

I had to blacklist each one by one on `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

/etc/postfix/sender_access:

```
fake-domain.com   DISCARD
fakeuser@realdomain.com DISCARD
```

Is there a way to make white-list that contains my server's real domain and all user accounts i have, and block any other fake senders, as automatic solution?

Comment: I recommend "Postfix: The Definitive Guide
A Secure and Easy-to-Use MTA for UNIX" at http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596002121.do or hire a consultant familiar with the Postfix MTA. What you ask is non-trivial.